# Removing double quotes from all dictionary keys in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Note: recommendations from similar questions and they didn't work

Issue: I have varios dict keys that include double quotes. I would like to remove them, and so far it's not working.

My data keys look like this:

```
data.keys()
dict_keys(['"Banana"', '"Tree"', '"Apple"', '"Watermelon" green'])
```

I have tried but nothing changes:

```
re.sub(r'"', '', str)
```

Comment: `new_str = old_str.replace('"','')`  note that it does not alter `old_str` but rather returns a new string

Comment: See comment above; regex is overkill for this task.

Comment: @JoranBeasley replace method is not applicable to dictionaries,I think. I will try again, thanks!

Comment: Please note [your code does not compile](https://ideone.com/cfVdRe). Please consider posting an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: of coarse it is ... you need to get the strings and replace them ...

Comment: How’d you end up in this situation to begin with? This suggests some mistreatment of strings which you should fix…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since my comment was not clear enough, here is how you would convert to a new dict with "fixed" keys

```
data = {'"Banana"':5, '"Tree"':7, '"Apple"':2, '"Watermelon" green':7}

new_data = {key.replace('"',''):val for key,val in data.items()}

print(new_data)
```

Comment: Thanks! @JoranBeasley

Answer (score 0):

For example I have one dict

```
    import re
    data = {'"a"':'a', '"b"':'b'}
    data.keys()
    raw = []
    for str in data:
         raw.appens(re.sub(r'"', '', str))
    print(raw)
```

Another way

```
data = {'"Banana"':"banana", '"Tree"':"xyz", '"Apple"':"sd", '"Watermelon" green':'test'}

raw = {re.sub(r'"', '', key):val for key,val in data.items()}

print(raw)
```